# Path of a swinging object on a rope

Tags: forces, newtonian-gravity, momentum, vectors

With my [lanyard](https://www.google.com/search?q=lanyard&rlz=1CASMAD_enUS678&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjQy9-wit_KAhXJMGMKHR-cBt8Q_AUIBygB&biw=1280&bih=665&safe=active&ssui=on) in hand (weighted by my keys), a gentle swinging motion will put the keys in pendulum motion, swinging back and forth. Pendulum motion is relatively easy to model since it is sinusoidal. With a more forceful swing, the keys on the will instead travel in a circular motion. Circular motion can also be modeled sinusoidally.

If I swing my lanyard with medium power, it will start to take the path of  a circle, but before the keys can reach maximum height, they begin to fall and start to model parabolic motion instead. I do not know how to model the path of my keys on my lanyard in this situation. I know it will transition from circular to parabolic motion once the vertical component of the velocity goes under zero, but I don't know what equation I could use. Any help?

Comment: "Sinusoidal" refers to position vs. time.  "Circular" refers to x vs. y position in space.  Your question is extremely poorly formulated.

Comment: This is a related, and possible duplicate of [this question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/201452/conditions-for-vertical-circular-motion).

Answer (score 1):

Note that pendulum motion is only sinusoidal for small angular displacements; as you increase the amount of swing the harmonic approximation fails.

Lagrangian mechanics gives you a handle on all of the cases.

Comment: Hi Peter, this is a comment not an answer

Comment: This is exactly how I would answer a student asking this question.  It is up to them to clarify their thoughts.

Comment: It's a very sparse post, to be sure, but it doesn't seem so obviously not-an-answer as to be deleted.